# Kdb+ CLI limits displayed results

Tags: kdb

I got problem with KDB+ CLI under windows as it cuts returned results to 20.

I am using(+ example what I get - trick with select[] is not working):

```
c:\q\w32>q.exe tick/r.q localhost:5000 localhost:5002 -p 5001
KDB+ 3.6 2018.12.24 Copyright (C) 1993-2018 Kx Systems
w32/ 4()core 4095MB XXXXXXXXX NONEXPIRE

Welcome to kdb+ 32bit edition
For support please see http://groups.google.com/d/forum/personal-kdbplus
Tutorials can be found at http://code.kx.com
To exit, type \\
To remove this startup msg, edit q.q
q)trade
time                 sym    price    size
-----------------------------------------
0D07:35:53.755779000 GS.N   179.5914 53
......
0D07:36:02.755693000 BA.N   127.7514 159
..
q)select[10000] from trade
time                 sym    price    size
-----------------------------------------
0D07:35:53.755779000 GS.N   179.5914 53
......
0D07:36:02.755693000 BA.N   127.7514 159
..
```

Middle ...... is used to remove line

Trailing .. is actual output in console(SQ complaint that post is mostly code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the console size using the c flag.

On the command line:

```
$ q -c maxRows maxCols
```

or in a q session

```
q)\c 50 50
```

By default it is set to 25 by 80.

```
q)\c
25 80i
```

You can also view a table via the web interface which is useful for large tables. From a browser

```
http://<hostname>:<port>
```

If you are running your q session locally, you can use `localhost` as the host name. On a Linux server you would need the server name or IP address. So

```
http://localhost:5001
```

will allow you to view tables on your local q session.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your console display size is restricted. Check out the `-c` command line arg to change it.

See  https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-c-console-size
and  https://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#c-console-size